# How to find the value of x given the following rectangular that has been divided into 4 parts?

Tags: word-problem, rectangles

A rectangle is divided into sections with the area shown. What is the value of X?
[image]

At first I didn't know what i would do than i noticed that X is 1/4th of the rectangular . But I don't know what to do next with this.

Comment: We have $\dfrac{40}{24}=\dfrac{x}{21}$.

Comment: $x$ is not $1/4$-th of the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d$ be the sides of the little rectangles (as shown in the picture).

$ab=24$, $ac=40$, $bd=21$, so $x=cd=\frac{(ac)(bd)}{ab}=\frac{40\cdot 21}{24}=35$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering Why is AB in the same box but only one letters in the other boxes? Can this be explained more simply

Comment: @MATHASKER Well, if the top side of $24$-rectangle is $b$, then the top side of $21$-rectangle is also $b$. Etc. I don't need to mark every single side.

Comment: @MATHASKER $cd=\frac{(ac)(bd)}{ab}$ is an identity, which is true for any numbers $a,b,c,d$. The fraction $\frac{(ac)(bd)}{ab}$ can be simplified to $cd$.

Comment: I get the way you labeled the diagram but why did you divide by ab? or just the way you did your math I didn't understand

Comment: Why is $$CD=AC*BD/AB$$

Comment: @MATHASKER $\frac{(ac)(bd)}{ab}=\frac{a}{a}\cdot \frac{b}{b}\cdot \frac{cd}{1}=1\cdot 1\cdot \frac{cd}{1}=cd$.

Comment: Oh okay so whenever these kind of questions arise, do i give them a identity so it would be easier for me to solve it.

Comment: @MATHASKER In your question you wrote $x$ is $1/4$-th of the rectangle, but it's incorrect.